# How to get the order of texts in grid layout after drag and drop operation is done in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview

I have a grid layout with texts where I can perform drag and drop. Everything is working fine but I want to record the order of the grid layout or text after some **DRAG AND DROP OPERATION** is done. I tried getting the texts after the drag is performed but its not giving me updated position.

Here is my code where I generate 'n' number of text views dynamically and add it to GRID LAYOUT

```
    text = new TextView[sizeofgrid];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofgrid; i++) {
        text[i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this); // create the txt view
        first = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        first.width = pergrid;
        text[i].setLayoutParams(first);
        text[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        first.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        text[i].setText(String.valueOf(finallist.get(i)));

        text[i].setTextSize(20);
        text[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
        text[i].setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#0B0B0B")));
        //  text[i].setPadding(5, 25, 10, 25);
        text[i].setPadding(5, 10, 0, 25);
         first.setMargins(0, 10, 5, 20);// margin can be set nly to layout and cant be set directly to textview
        text[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                final ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", ""); 
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view); 
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                Log.d(tag, "calleddd");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Here is the code which performs drag

```
   class DragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) { // the view which we are dragging and the events whcih gets triggred

       final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION: // if the shadow of the view is within the bounds for a long amt of time , it will get triggred
                // do nothing if hovering above own position
                dragflag = true;
                if (view == v) return true; // can or cant be thr..makes no diff
                // get the new list index
                final int index = calculateNewIndex(event.getX(), event.getY()); // as soon as we start moving from current pos, it will start
                //calculating new value and will get relocated
                // remove the view from the old position
                gl.removeView(view); //remove the view from original pos
                // and push to the new
                gl.addView(view, index); // add the view to newly cal pos
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                //tested by retrieving the text of textview after dropping but it hasn't got updated.

                for(int i = 0; i < sizeofgrid; i++)
                {
                    Log.d(tag,"thetexssis"+text[i].getText().toString());
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                if (!event.getResult()) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tested by retrieving the text of the text view but it gives me the same order of text before drag and drop is performed. I don't know how to get the order of the current text view in grid layout.

Any help would be great !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by the following code,

```
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeofgrid; k++) {
        View view = gl.getChildAt(k);
        Log.d(tag,"droppedis");
        // Do something with v.
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            TextView editText = (TextView) view;
            arr.add(editText.getText().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "thelistis" + arr);
        }

    }
```

I am getting all the views from the parent and checking if its an instance of textview. If so, then I am getting the text from the textview and storing in a list.